# How can I get the position of 2D Map with the value of TLE for the satellite?

Tags: satellite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fU52.png)

Hello, I am a developer of Unreal in Korea.
We are currently using a plug-in called MaxQ to create a satellite tracking program for our company.
The TLE value at the sample level in MaxQ allowed us to locate the satellite in 3D
There's no way to find out the 2D location and expected path like the image
I've been looking for it on Google for 2 days, but I can't figure it out.
I feel very sorry and sad about my lack of mathematical knowledge...
I need your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fU52.png)

Comment: Can you please provide some examples about the 3D coordinates you have

Comment: There's plenty of software available.  https://www.google.com/search?q=tle+orbit+determination+software   Lots of this software can also be used to determine the ground track of an orbiting satellite/

Comment: @AliIsmaeel 

I don't know exactly the example you said.

Shamefully, I didn't even understand the formula for finding 3D coordinates.
The coordinates were obtained using only the functions provided by the plug-in.

Comment: I'm currently looking for a function available in the plug-in called MaxQ.